# How to get time in following fragment code

Tags: java

Why does `getTime()` method return `null` value? Its returning a non-null value when `time` is declared as a `static` variable, but then we can not make objects with different time.

```
package timecounter;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Timerx extends TimerTask {

    int H, M, S;
    Timer timer;
    String time;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        S++;
        if (S >= 60) {
            M++;
            S = 0;
            if (M >= 60) {
                H++;
                M = 0;
                if (H >= 12) {
                    H = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        this.time = String.format("%2d:%2d:%2d", H, M, S);
        System.out.print("Running");
    }
    public void start() {
        timer.schedule(new Timerx(), 1000, 1000);
    }
    public Timerx() {
        this.timer = new Timer();
    }
    public String getTime() {// here return null value
        return time;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its return when "string static time" variable"? My guess is that you're calling `getTime()` on a new instance, rather than one where the timer had actually fired.

Comment: `start()` seems to schedule a `new Timerx()` rather than `this`. I suppose that is the issue.

Comment: actually I cant get time it return null value. when I changed time variable to string its working but  timeCounter in every instance return same time

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
    timer.schedule(new Timerx(), 1000, 1000);
```

With:

```
    timer.schedule(this, 1000, 1000);
```

However this peace of code is not very nice. You want to have multiple timer counters but each timertask has its own timer. Each timer needs a thread for its services. It is better to use multiple timertasks with one timer.

E.g. replace

```
    Timer timer;
```

with:

```
    static Timer timer = new Timer();
```

or extract this to a separate singleton class e.g. CounterService.